# Display a field in the homepage odoo

Tags: odoo, erp

I have created a module in odoo with a model called "product" and a string field called "formelab" , I want to display this "formelab" field just under the price on the product sheet.

[image: This is the product page which I called PROD]

[image: That's the shop page]

I want to display "ABCCCC" on the PROD sheet under "$1.00"

that's the product_template.xml in the views folder

``

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="formelab_ref_id_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">access.product.view.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='type']" position="after">
                <field name="formelab_ref"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

`and that's the product.py in the models folder`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import api, fields, models


class product(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    formelab_ref = fields.Char("Formelab")
```

``

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the [products_item](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/website_sale/views/templates.xml#L102) template.

The following code add the `formelab_ref` value after the `priceCurrency` span:

```xml
<template inherit_id="website_sale.products_item" id="daz">
    <xpath expr="//span[@itemprop='priceCurrency']" position="after">
        <span t-field="product.formelab_ref"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```